# mpi_send mpi_recv rounding error

Tags: mpi, rounding-error

I would like to ask if the functions mpi_send and mpi_recv have any rounding error similar to mpi_reduce ? I thought it should not be since the rounding error of the mpr_reduce function comes from the difference in the order of processor executing but the functions mpi_send and mpr_recv do not have a similar procedure.

Then I would like to ask if it is logical to verify the calculation of a parallel code with only mpi_send and mpi_recv functions by compare its results with a serial code ?

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`MPI_Send` and `MPI_Recv` do not perform rounding *per se*. But there could still be differences between the results from the serial code and the parallel one on systems, where higher internal precision is used. A typical example is x86 when the x87 FPU is used (mostly in 32-bit code). x87 operates on a small stack of 80-bit values and all operations, even those involving values of lesser precision, are performed with 80-bit internal precision. Whenever an intermediate value has to be transferred to another MPI rank, it first gets rounded to either `float` or `double`, unless the non-standard extended precision type is used, which removes significant bits that would otherwise be there if the value were to remain in the x87 stack. This is not an MPI-specific problem as it might also manifest itself in serial code as different results depending on the level of register optimisation performed by the compiler.